# Install the module generator-primeng-charts in Jhipster-generator , Error "Can't read .yo-rc.json"

Tags: jhipster, primeng

I installed the module primeng-charts 
$ yarn global add generator-jhipster-primeng-charts
but when I launch $yo jhipster-primeng-charts  , an error appeared "ERROR! Can't read .yo-rc.json"  . How to fix that ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYlbT.png)

Comment: But I want to add the  module primeng in the generator-jhipster not in the project generated .

Comment: Modules are added to a project not to the generator. @Alexandre GC is right. Please accept his answer.

Comment: Ok thank for your answer . There is no solution to integrate primeng component into a generator jhipster ?!!

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by "integrating a primeng  component into the generator" ? Do you want to extend the generator or use primeng in your projects?

Comment: I want to use the components of primeng such as charts , panel in the generator jhispter . as a result , i will get similar projects with primeng component .

Comment: So you want to write a module or fork the generator to modify it? This is very far from your original question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate a JHipster project first and then run `yo jhipster-primeng-charts` at the root of that project.